# How to install "Gerrit" in linux machine without any error?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, gerrit

I am not able to install **Gerrit on my Linux server** and getting below mentioned error.

My config file:

[image: Image of Gerrit config with error]

Error:

```
fatal: DbInjector failed
fatal: Unable to determine SqlDialect
fatal:   caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "y"'.
fatal:   caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "y"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you made a mistake with the database server name and port specification. They are both specified as 'y'

[image]

Comment: thanks for your above solution@uncletall... now getting different error (mentioned below)                                                                       fatal: DbInjector failed
fatal: Unable to determine SqlDialect
fatal:   caused by java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'gerrit'@'ip-10-xx-x-xx.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)

Comment: Check if you entered the correct password, you can find it in the /home/gerrit2/review_site/etc/secure.config

Comment: And you might want to try to connect to 127.0.0.1